# Simple React State Behaves unpredictably when updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to create a state which will keep track of a list by the states value.
It increases or decreases by 1.
However, it does not work exactly how I am expecting it to.
I am using the up and down arrow keys to increment or decrement the value, and whenever I "change direction" it updates the state once more in the previous direction before it goes the correct way. I provide an image with console logs to make it clear what I mean.

[image: console-log]

I will also provide some code of course.

```
export const SearchBar = (props) => {
...
const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState(0);
...
...
const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    const keyPressed = e.key;
    if (keyPressed === "ArrowDown") {
      setCurrentItem(currentItem +1);
      
    } else if (keyPressed === "ArrowUp" && currentItem >= 0) {
      setCurrentItem(currentItem -1);
      
    } else if (keyPressed === "Enter") {
      dispatch(setSearchTerm(''));
      setCurrentItem(0);

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Where in the code are you logging the new state?

Comment: Directly after "setCurrentItem" which seems to be another mistake by me. I have now been watching the state in chrome dev-tools and notice that the state actually changes as I am expecting it too, but sometimes it delays, I guess enough for the console.log to print out the incorrect value. aargh, javascript :)

Comment: This isn't a JS issue but more to do with how React updates state which generally is done asynchronously and in batches (mostly). You can use [`useEffect` to execute code when state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) updates. For example: `useEffect(() => console.log(currentItem), [currentItem]);`

Comment: PS there's no standard to how dev consoles are written. [Some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) tend to log things differently to others.

Comment: [Even more reading](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 1):

When mutating states based on the previous states you should make use of the useState callback. Instead of:

```
setCurrentItem(currentItem + 1)
```

try:

```
setCurrentItem((prevState) => prevState + 1)
```

This will ensure that you always get the latest previous state when updating it.